# Cron Job In Custom Plugin Not Working In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, kubernetes-cronjob

I have added this cronjob in my WordPress custom plugin but when I run the function manually it is working but through cronjob, it is not working. Here is my code! All the plugin files are loaded correctly not showing any error.
Can anybody help me to sort this out! I have tried a lot but still, it is not working.

```
    <?php

         if (!wp_next_scheduled('generateusedcarsfeed'))
        {
            wp_schedule_event(time() , '5mins', 'generateusedcarsfeed');
        }

        add_action('generateusedcarsfeed', 'generate_used_car_feed');
if (!wp_next_scheduled('generateusedcarsfeed'))
{
    wp_schedule_event(time() , '5mins', 'generateusedcarsfeed');
}

add_action('generateusedcarsfeed', 'generate_used_car_feed');

// Getting all used cars with all data

function generate_used_car_feed(){
    try{
        // for opening the csv file
        $file = fopen('all-cars-feed.csv', 'r');
        fwrite($file, '');
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        chmod('all-cars-feed.csv', 0777);

        // for creating array from csv file
        $file="all-cars-feed.csv";
        $csv= file_get_contents($file);
        $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
        $json_csv_arr = json_encode($array);
        $my_array_csv = json_decode($json_csv_arr, true);

        // for getting used car list from databse, only take publish used car
        global $wpdb;
        $query = "SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
        INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE meta_key = 'car_registration_number' 
        AND post_status = 'publish'";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        $json_reg_num = json_encode($result);
        $my_array = json_decode($json_reg_num, true);
        print_r($my_array); 
        foreach ($my_array as $value) {
            $car_reg_array = $value['meta_value'];
            $Post_id= $value['post_id'];
            $isTrue=true;

            $ch = fopen("all-cars-feed.csv", "r");
            while($row = fgetcsv($ch)) {
            if (in_array($car_reg_array, $row)) {
                echo 'found</hr>';
                $isTrue=false;
            }
         }
        if($isTrue)
        {
            $wpdb->query(
              'UPDATE   '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts SET post_status = "trash"
               WHERE ID = "'.$Post_id.'"');
        }
}

        //fclose($file);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        $txt = 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

        fwrite($fileLoger, $txt);
        fclose($fileLoger);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this `5mins` interval really exists in your setup. Try adding this code to make sure this actually exists (if it does already, it won't break stuff):

```
function add_custom_cron_schedules($schedules){
  if (!isset($schedules["5mins"])) {
    $schedules["5min"] = array(
      'interval' => 5*60,
      'display' => __('Every 5 minutes'));
  }
  return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules','add_custom_cron_schedules');
```

If you want to retrieve currently available schedules, you can also use `wp_get_schedules()` and check out if a certain key (like '5mins') exists.